# How to count duplicates by group within a cell and ignore the blank cells unless the group only has blank cells in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that is a in the form shown below.

I want to find out if the entries per group are duplicates.

The problem is that some groups have a mix of blank and non blank cells. The duplicate function would count the blank cells as a unique entry. I want to count the non blank entries only when there is a mix of blank and non blank and, if the group has only blank cells, I want to count the blanks as a unique entry.

So, if I had something like the data frame below, the counts would be 2 for group A, 1 for group B and 1 for group C. I'd then compare this number to the number of groups to see if there are any non repeated values within each groups.

The only way I can think of is by taking each column one by one and removing all the blank cells then using the duplicates function. The problem with this is that I loads of columns and multiple data frame so that option wouldn't be feasible.

In my actualy dataset, it is likely that there are only repeated values per group, but I need some way of confirming this. The idea is that, if there are only repeated values within each group, I can remove all of them and have a row per group.

Any help would be really appreciated

```
test <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3),
  value1 = c("", "a", "b", "b", "", "", "", "", "")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using *base*:

```
aggregate(.~group, data = test, FUN = function(i){
  n <- length(unique(i[ i != ""]))
  if(all(i == "")) n = 1
  n
  })

#   group value1
# 1     A      2
# 2     B      1
# 3     C      1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a small helper function and apply by group (here is a data.table version)

```
library(data.table)

f <- \(v) if(all(v=="")) 1L else uniqueN(v[v!=""])
setDT(test)[, f(value1), group]
```

Here is a `dplyr` based version of the same:

```
library(dplyr)

f <- \(v) if(all(v=="")) 1L else n_distinct(v[v!=""])
test %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(ct = f(value1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ all(. == '') + n_distinct(.[!. == ''])))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  group value1
  <fct>  <int>
1 A          2
2 B          1
3 C          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
   reframe(value1 = pmax(length(setdiff(value1, "")), 1), .by = 'group')
```

-output

```
   group value1
1     A      2
2     B      1
3     C      1
```